# NextJS - Call js function when onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to call js function on client side when I click button/div elements.

**This scenario works.(addEventListener)**

**MyComponent.js**

```
import Script from 'next/script'
export default function MyComponent({ props }) {
    return (
             <>
             <div className="slider-buttons">
                  <div key="1" data-id="1" className="slider-button active"></div>
                  <div key="2" data-id="2" className="slider-button"></div>
                  <div key="3" data-id="3" className="slider-button"></div>
                  <div key="4" data-id="4" className="slider-button"></div>
             </div>
             <Script src="/assets/slider.js" strategy="afterInteractive" />
             </>
            )
}
```

**Slider.js**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-button");
Array.from(elements).forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', ClientClick);
});

function ClientClick(e) {
    if (e && e.target) {
        var clickedId = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
        // DOM Manipulation
    }
}
```

**This scenario I want (without addEventListener)**

**MyComponent.js**

```
import Script from 'next/script'
export default function MyComponent({ props }) {
    return (
             <>
             <div className="slider-buttons">
                  <div key="1" data-id="1" onClick="ClientClick(1)" className="slider-button active"></div>
                  <div key="2" data-id="2" onClick="ClientClick(2)" className="slider-button"></div>
                  <div key="3" data-id="3" onClick="ClientClick(3)" className="slider-button"></div>
                  <div key="4" data-id="4" onClick="ClientClick(4)" className="slider-button"></div>
             </div>
             <Script src="/assets/slider.js" strategy="afterInteractive" />
             </>
            )
}
```

**Slider.js**

```
function ClientClick(clickedId ) {
    // DOM Manipulation
}
```

Returns an error

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.

Is that possible to call JS function on client-side without addEventListener?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onClick` in react expects a function to be passed, in your case you are passing a value returned by the function call.

So just change your `onClick={ClientClick(1)}` to `onClick={() => ClientClick(1)}`

Changing it to the below code should work.

```
<div key="1" data-id="1" onClick="() => ClientClick(1)" className="slider-button active"></div>
<div key="2" data-id="2" onClick="() => ClientClick(2)" className="slider-button"></div>
<div key="3" data-id="3" onClick="() => ClientClick(3)" className="slider-button"></div>
<div key="4" data-id="4" onClick="() => ClientClick(4)" className="slider-button"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Events handling in React (or Next.js) look little different than in a vanilla JS.

Check it out:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html